# Asymmetric diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I have two branches in my git repo, `A` and `B` with have a common ancestor `C`. The commits from `C` to `A` may contain a squashed merge, or otherwise rewritten history, of the commits from `C` to `B`. How can I determine this? Is there a way to do it with `git diff`?

In general terms, I want to know if the commits from `C` to `A` contain all the textual changes in the commits from `C` to `B`. `git diff A B` doesn't quite do what I want because it will also report all the changes in the commits from `C` to `A` which are **not** in the commits from `C` to `B`. I only want the diff for changes in the commits from `C` to `B` which are not in the commits from `C` to `A`. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit (per question edit): I don't think there's a completely reliable way to do this.  Fundamentally, the problem is that if some change from `C` to `A` *overlaps* some change from `C` to `B`—would undo or overwrite or modify the diff between `C` and `B`—it's impossible to tell in general why that's the case.

That is, we're given a divergent commit graph like this:

```
       a1--a2--...--a_i_max-minus-1--A
      /
...--C
      \
       b0--...--b_j_max-minus-1--B
```

(there's no constraint that either *i = j* or *i ≠ j*, i.e., the differing lengths here is not meant to imply one or the other).  Here the commit labeled `A` is really just the final A<sub>i</sub>, and similarly for `B`.  You want to discover whether C-vs-B is contained in any of C-vs-A<sub>i</sub>, or even A<sub>k</sub>-vs-A<sub>l</sub> for some *k < l*.  You could exhaustively test to see if that's true, but that would be expensive, and also miss any cases where it's "logically true" but the final commit of the sequence is not quite the same as C-vs-B, likely because it was modified to resolve a merge conflict.

The exhaustive test is probably as close as you can get.  It would be best if you could enforce a work-flow requirement that there be a commit message or commit note attached to the squash merge in the A<sub>i</sub> series of commits: then you just need to enumerate them and examine each for the note saying *I am the result of squashing C vs B*.

(original answer follows)

---

The question is not well-formed—at least not in Git-land—because there is no such thing as "the changes in `A`".  If `A` is a branch name, it names one specific commit. To find *changes* you must name *two* commits, and `git diff` them.  The same holds for branch-name `B`: you must pick some earlier commit in order to turn the snapshot in (the tip commit on branch) `B` into a change-set (with respect to some earlier commit).

In general, when people ask this, they have a particular third commit in mind:

```
          o--o--A   <-- BranchA
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--B   <-- BranchB
```

This third commit, marked `*` here, is the place where the two branches "join up", aka the *merge base*.

If commit `*` is not the commit you intended to use as the (single) third point for producing this asymmetric diff, none of the rest of this answer applies.  But if it *is*, the way to find it is to do the merge, then compare the result of the merge to whichever branch-tip you care about.

The merge will take the union of all changes (from `*` to `A`, and from `*` to `B`) and put them into the merge commit:

```
$ git checkout --detach BranchA # doesn't matter which one we use
$ git merge BranchB
```

results (if there are no merge conflicts) in:

```
          o--o--A   <-- BranchA
         /       \
...--o--*         M   <-- HEAD (detached)
         \       /
          o--o--B   <-- BranchB
```

You can now see what `*`-vs-`A` looked like if one started with `B` by comparing (diffing) `B` vs `M`:

```
$ git diff HEAD^2 HEAD    # or git diff BranchB HEAD
```

Anything that shows up here are changes contributed by the `*`-vs-`A` diff that were not also contributed by the `*`-vs-`B` diff.

Likewise, comparing the merge commit against commit `A` will show changes contributed by the `*`-vs-`B` diff that were not already in the `*`-vs-`A` diff:

```
$ git diff HEAD^1 HEAD
```

Using `git show -m`, you can see both at the same time, as two separate diffs, since that is what `-m` does with `git show`.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. I need to read through it a few times to digest it all and determine if this does what I am looking for. To reword my question in terms of your example here, I want to know if the changes from *-to-A appear in *-to-B. I do not care about additional changes which may have been introduced in *-to-B.

Comment: In that case, you might be able to get away with checking that merge-vs-B is empty.

Comment: I am still trying to find a better solution for this. I have revised my OP to hopefully be more clear about what I am looking for. If you have time, please take a look.